# Javascript systax for URL contatenation

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am pulling data from a JSON file into a map and form. I would like to link to new tab with directions to given location. How do I write this?

Working code that opens Yelp link:

```
<tr><th>Yelp</th><td><a class='url-break' href='" + feature.properties.YelpURL + "' target='_blank'>" + feature.properties.YelpURL + "</a></td></tr>
```

Not working code for Google Directions using lat long

```
<tr><th>Directio</th><td><a class='url-break' href='" + https://www.google.com/maps/dir/ + feature.properties.geo_longitude + feature.properties.geo_latitude + "' target='_blank'>" + Get Directions + "</a></td></tr>
```

[The app in progress](http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/keyelement/index1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quotes are in the wrong place, replace

```
<a class='url-break' href='" + https://www.google.com/maps/dir/ + feature.properties.geo_longitude + feature.properties.geo_latitude + "' target='_blank'>
```

with

```
<a class='url-break' href='https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + feature.properties.geo_longitude +","+ feature.properties.geo_latitude + "' target='_blank'>
```

Comment: And he/she was missing a comma between latitude and longitude ;)